# website works locally but not on NodeJS webserver, beginner

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services

After setting up some files (index.html and ws.js [which sets up the server]), I can't seem to include any additional JS files that my website uses. I've tried to `require()` the additional files, but to no avail. When I run `node ws.js`, the server comes up and index.html displays, but the buttons (which have functionality defined in run.js) say "replace is not undefined". I run the server via the command`node ws.js`, and access the website via the URL `localhost:8080`. I originally had no module exports, and it still didn't work then. I've gotten all this to work when I just double click index.html, so I know it works locally (if that's the correct term).

Here is my ws.js file:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var events = require("events");
var serveStatic = require("serve-static");
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

var run = require("./run.js");
run();

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
        // Send the HTTP header 
        // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
        // Content Type: text/plain
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

        response.write(data);
        return response.end();
    });
}).listen(8080);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
console.log(__filename);
console.log(__dirname);

(function () {
    function hi() {
        alert("This is working!");
    }
})();
```

Here is my run.js file:

```
function run() {
    function testerClicked() {
        alert("Tester has been clicked!");
    }

    function replace() {
        var temp = (document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML === "This is a button." ? "This button has been pressed!" : "This is a button.");
        document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML = temp;
    }
}

module.exports = run;
```

This is the line where I'm calling the function in HTML:

```
<button id='tester' onclick="replace()">This is a button.</button>
```

Sorry if this is a basic question. I'm just starting to learn about servers and JavaScript/HTML/CSS.

Comment: It appears you're serving your html file, but are you serving your additional javascript/asset files?

Comment: I'm linking the JavaScript files in my index.html. Does the "serving" need to be done in ws.js?

Comment: When you go to a webpage, the index.html file in your node server responds and downloads that file. If in your index.html you have `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` the browser will make another request to the server to request `bundle.js` (Which your ws.js file doesn't handle). Try checking out [this](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) for serving static content.

Comment: I checked out the link and saw the section for "Serving using express". Do I need to integrate this code with the code I currently have in ws.js? I think that would essentially make it so that I create the server, and then serve the JavaScript files

Comment: Yes................

Comment: I changed my ws.js file to the code given under "Serving using express" section, and I changed the file system structure (i.e. adding a couple directories). After figuring out how to define the function correctly in the run.js file while having my ws.js file import all the external files, everything works when I'm running the website with NodeJS! Thanks!

Comment: I'll convert my comment to an answer, so that you can mark as accepted/gain rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not currently serving anything from your node.js server other than your index.html file.

When you go to a webpage, the index.html file in your node server responds and downloads that file. If in your index.html you have `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` the browser will make another request to the server to request `bundle.js` (Which your ws.js file doesn't handle). Try checking out [this](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) for serving static content.

Comment: Worked like a charm! The link was especially useful :)